# How To Decide Rest API Response Life Cycle

Tags: rest, http, express

I'm going to develop some REST APIs with NodeJS and Express framework. User API is one of them. But I'm confused to send the proper response for each and every scenario of the API. What order of sending response HTTP status I've decided are following:

**GET /users HTTP/1.1**

1. `400 Bad Request` Check if URL is malformed.
2. `401 Unauthorized` Check if access token is not provided
3. `403 Forbidden` Check if user in access token is not allowed to view these resources
4. `200 OK` If no, one or more records found

**GET /users/:id HTTP/1.1**

1. `400 Bad Request` Check if URL is malformed.
2. `422 Unprocessable Entity` Check if ID is not validated properly for e.g Non-Numeric string
3. `401 Unauthorized` Check if access token is not provided
4. `403 Forbidden` Check if user in access token is not allowed to view this entity
5. `404 Not Found` If the requested is not found
6. `200 OK` If the entity is found properly
7. `500 Internal Server Error` If there was any kind of issue in MySQL or Node server side during entity find.

**POST /users HTTP/1.1**

1. `415 Unsupported Media Type` Check if the header `Content-Type` is not application/json.
2. `400 Bad Request` Check if the JSON format is not proper or any syntax error present
3. `401 Unauthorized` Check if access token is not provided
4. `403 Forbidden` Check if user in access token is not allowed to create a new entity
5. `422 Unprocessable Request` If certain validations failed in the request body parameters
6. `409 Conflict Issue` If username or email in the request is not available or already exist.
7. `200 OK with new entity Location Header` If entity created successfully.
8. `500 Internal Server Error` If there was any kind of issue in MySQL or Node server side during entity creation.

**PUT /users/:id HTTP/1.1**

1. `415 Unsupported Media Type` Check if the header `Content-Type` is not application/json.
2. `400 Bad Request` Check if the JSON format is not proper or any syntax error present
3. `422 Unprocessable Entity` Check if ID is not validated properly for e.g Non-Numeric string
4. `401 Unauthorized` Check if access token is not provided
5. `403 Forbidden` Check if user in access token is not allowed to update this entity
6. `422 Unprocessable Request` If certain validations failed in the request body parameters
7. `409 Conflict Issue` If username or email in the request rather than this user is not available or already exist.
8. `204 OK with no content` If entity updated successfully.
9. `500 Internal Server Error` If there was any kind of issue in MySQL or Node server side during entity update.

**DELETE /users/:id HTTP/1.1**

1. `400 Bad Request` Check if URL is malformed.
2. `422 Unprocessable Entity` Check if ID is not validated properly for e.g Non-Numeric string
3. `401 Unauthorized` Check if access token is not provided
4. `403 Forbidden` Check if user in access token is not allowed to delete this entity
5. `404 Not Found` If the requested is not found
6. `204 OK with no content` If the entity deleted successfully
7. `500 Internal Server Error` If there was any kind of issue in MySQL or Node server side during entity deletion

So what I wanted to discuss on Stackoverflow is:

1. Are all the above **order** of step correct or need to think once again?
2. Will this API break in any scenario that will lead the end users to see non JSON response?

Comment: This isn't a forum for discussion. Writing it and testing it should answer your questions, so *do that*.

Comment: I know that but I wanted to know the right approach.

Comment: You knew and wrote it anyway? **That is worse!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above all status codes are fine now apart from that Twitter does a great job of having HTTP status codes documented and having specific error codes for other issues too. Some are tied to HTTP status codes, which is fine, but many are not. Some are also tied to the same status code, highlighting the issues raised above.Check this document below.

[Error Codes & Responses](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/response-codes)

Hope this helps.